# How is the use of を broken down in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-を

I've been reading a Visual Novel, and I came across this sentence:

> リリーはくすくす笑い、ティースプーンを置くと、カップとソーサーを手にゆっくりテーブルに向かってくる。

What's throwing me off is the use of **を** right after 「カップとソーサー～」I put the sentence through DeepL and the translation comes out as: "Lily chuckles, puts down her teaspoon, and slowly makes her way to the table with her cup and saucer". So I get that this **を** may be related to the use of the を particle with 「来る」and 「行く」which gives the meaning of "along," "across," or "through", although I'm basing this on 「来る」used as a suffix on 「向かう」. I'd like to know for sure how this can be broken down since this is the first time I'm coming across this grammar structure.